# Skip certain sentence in parsing text

Tags: php

I wanna parse text. There's a strange sentence like `B R I E F I N G S I N B I O I N F O R M A T I C S` I wanna skip theat sentence. here's the code

```
<?php
$text = 'B R I E F I N G S I N B I O I N F O R M A T I C S. Because many biomedical entities have multiple names and abbreviations, it would be advantageous to have an automated means to collect these synonyms and abbreviations to aid users doing literature searches.';

$reg = '/(?<=[.!?]|[.!?][\'"])\s+/';
foreach(preg_split($reg, $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY) as $sentence){
    foreach(preg_split('/\s+/', $sentence) as $words){
       if (count(strlen($words)>1)){
        //I don't know what to do
    }
    }
}
?>
```

But, it still wrong, how to recognize pattern sentence like `B R I E F I N G S I N B I O I N F O R M A T I C S` ? thank you

Comment: Is that string going to be the same in all cases?

Comment: @Asad no, `text` in my question was just example, I just take 2 sentences of big paragraphs, I'm working in many paragraphs

Answer (score 1):

what about this? This work if length of all words in sentence equal 1.

```
   <?php
    $text = 'B R I E F I N G S I N B I O I N F O R M A T I C S. Because many biomedical entities have multiple names and abbreviations, it would be advantageous to have an automated means to collect these synonyms and abbreviations to aid users doing literature searches.';

$reg = '/(?<=[.!?]|[.!?][\'"])\s+/';
foreach(preg_split($reg, $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY) as $sentence){
    foreach(preg_split('/\s+/', $sentence) as $words){
       $isStrange = true;
       if (strlen($words)>1){
        $isStrange = false;
    }
    if ($isStrange) echo $sentence.' is very strange!';
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work provided the string is the same each time

```
<?php
$text = 'B R I E F I N G S I N B I O I N F O R M A T I C S. Because many biomedical entities have multiple names and abbreviations, it would be advantageous to have an automated means to collect these synonyms and abbreviations to aid users doing literature searches.';

$text = str_replace("B R I E F I N G S I N B I O I N F O R M A T I C S. ","",$text); // <--- added this

$reg = '/(?<=[.!?]|[.!?][\'"])\s+/';
foreach(preg_split($reg, $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY) as $sentence){
    foreach(preg_split('/\s+/', $sentence) as $words){
       if (count(strlen($words)>1)){
        //I don't know what to do
    }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: This won't work if the string varies, but it will if it doesn't

Comment: the `text` is only example, that won't work if the string varies, agree with Chris..

Answer (score 1):

From the sentence you've shown, I would remove sentences solely comprising space infused capitals, at the start of your text:

```
echo preg_replace('/^[A-Z](?:\s[A-Z])+\./', '', $text);
```